# Spring Boot application can't resolve the org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication?

Tags: java, android, rest, spring-boot

I'm trying to build a Restful Web Service using this tutorial : https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/ . But i got stuck at this eroor .

I have also some problems in the build gradle

`Error:(26, 0) Cannot change configuration ':app:classpath' after it has been resolved.`

It Looks like this .( I have some extra dependencies because i'm trying to make the Restful Web Service in my android app).

```
   `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sample.foo.simplelocationapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.4.3.RELEASE")

        }
    }
    plugins {
        id "org.springframework.boot" version "1.4.3.RELEASE"
    }

    subprojects {
        apply plugin: 'java'
        apply plugin: 'eclipse'
        apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
        apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
        apply plugin: 'idea'
    }



    jar {
        baseName = 'gs-spring-boot'
        version =  '0.1.0'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8


    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:1.0.1.RELEASE'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.3.2'
    compile 'com.android.databinding:compiler:1.0-rc0'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-web:4.2.1.RELEASE'
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") {
        exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    }
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty")
    // end::jetty[]
    // tag::actuator[]
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    // end::actuator[]
    testCompile("junit:junit")
}
```

`

Can somebody help me please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point is that you just can't put Restful Web Services in your Android app. The Android application is the Client and consumes information served by a Server (a.k.a. the Restful Web Services provider).

[image]

The client (green box) is your Android app. The server (blue box) is the spring boot application.

I suggest you to download the example https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/ as it is and just run it. It will expose some simple Json and you can try to make some calls from the browser to them.

Exposed resources are running on port 8080 and are the following:

- /greeting
- /greeting?name=myValue

Work on a local network, find out the ip of the computer where you are running the server and try to consume this resources from your Android app!

Hope this will help :D

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer ! I can see now what i was doing wrong .

Comment: So the thing is , i want to send from the client (android app) a location in latitude and longitude to a server that i already  made in Java and store that date in my database . And after that show the added locations in a monitor i made in html on a map .  Can you give me a clue how to do it ?   Thank you again !

Comment: Hmm, since you already store the information in the database, the next step is to display the position. If you know AngularJS, you can use it. You can define a Controller (SpringMVC) that sends an AngularJS app with an embedded map in it (Google Maps). There are a lot of libraries for Angular that help you using it!

Comment: Great , i'll start working on it . Thank you  for your help and your time .